# Datatable to Datasetxsd?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reporting

I'm having some problems with reporting and I thought you could help me:

I have created a dataset (mydata.xsd). I also have designed a Report.rdlc, and I did the same with a frame with a ReportViewe inside, wich use mydata.xsd as a source data.

I have designed mydata.xsd to have 2 columns  (user, time). How would you fill this dataset? The reporting tool get the data from this "xsd" file, but I never fill it anywhere. I fill another dataset I have as a private member of my class, and that's all.

Thanks in advance.

Pablo Reyes

Answer (score 0):

What dataset are you filling and from what dataset are you want to fetch records ? If u have two columns say user and time then create a dataset with wizard , it will generate the queries and tables. Now set this dataset as the datasource of report. From Field Explore drag drop the column to report.

Comment: I have done that. The problem is that the data is generated in runtime. I have a dataset with 15 columns, and I only need 2 of then. Then, I'd like to show it in the report, wich is linked to a DataSet.xsd.